# Bus source and destination

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm working on the mysql query where I have to check BUS starting point and last stop point.

My Table has two field i.e. Source and Destination with below values.

Source Destination

```
A      B

B      C

D      E

E      F

G      H

H      I

A      B

C      D

E      F

G      H
```

As per table data, Bus starting point A and It use to cover following destination B,C,D,E,F,G,H and endup in I point.  Second time again It would have start with some starting point say A and endup in H. So, result should be like below:-

Source Destination

```
A      I

A      H
```

Edit: Have used below query but It's not returning unique rows

```
SELECT T.Source, T.Destination
FROM BUS_Morning T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BUS_Morning T2 WHERE T2.Source = T.Destination)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Can you share the query you have ?

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: SQL Server 2005

Comment: Could you please **edit your question** and explain how you determined those results? Thanks.

Comment: OK, starting at the first row A -> B - do we then use "B" as the source and follow B -> C, C -> D, D -> E, E -> F? And then there's no "F" in the SOURCE column, so how do we get from "F" to anywhere?